# Multi Object Lock On Issue:

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am working on a lock on system for my project. I am currently implementing a way to lock on with multiple targets and cycle through them directionally based on the user's input.

However, when in utilization. It seems that the check for the target to the right of the targeted object never updates, which stagnates the proper order. I have no idea why this is happening, as it's the same code as the left that updates. Anyway, taking a look is appreciated and ideas more so!
Part 1:

```
void ManageTargets()
    {
        shortDistLeft = Mathf.Infinity;
        shortDistRight = Mathf.Infinity;

        for (int i = 0; i < availableTars.Count; i++)
        {


            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, availableTars[i].transform.position);
            

            if (dist <= shortestDist)
            {
                shortestDist = dist;
                closestLockOnTarget = availableTars[i];
                currentTarget = closestLockOnTarget;

            }
            if(dist >= maxLockDist)
            {
                lockOn = false;
                shortestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
                availableTars.Clear();
                currentTarget = null;
                closestLockOnTarget = null;
                PlayerStateManager.instance.camState = 0;
            }
            if (lockOn)
            {
                Vector3 relativeEnemyPos = currentTarget.transform.InverseTransformPoint(availableTars[i].transform.position);
                var distanceFromLeftTarget = currentTarget.transform.position.x - availableTars[i].transform.position.x;
                var distanceFromRightTarget = currentTarget.transform.position.x + availableTars[i].transform.position.x;

                if (relativeEnemyPos.x  > 0.00 && distanceFromLeftTarget < shortDistLeft)
                {
                    shortDistLeft = distanceFromLeftTarget;
                    leftLockTarget = availableTars[i];
                }
                if (relativeEnemyPos.x < 0.00 && distanceFromRightTarget < shortDistRight)
                {
                    shortDistRight = distanceFromRightTarget;
                    rightLockTarget = availableTars[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and Part 2:

```
void lockOnLogic()
    {
        if (lockOn)
        {
            
            if (currentTarget == null)
            {

               camRecenter();
                lockOn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerStateManager.instance.camState = 1;

            }


            if (lockOnMoveL == true) {
                lockOnMoveL = false;
                
                if (leftLockTarget != null)
                {
                    
                    currentTarget = leftLockTarget;
                    
                }
                ManageTargets();
            }
            if (lockOnMoveR == true){
                lockOnMoveR = false;
                    
                if (rightLockTarget != null)
                    {
                        currentTarget = rightLockTarget;
                        

                    }
                ManageTargets();
            }
                    
            
            

        }
        else
        {
            shortestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
            availableTars.Clear();
            currentTarget = null;
            closestLockOnTarget = null;
            PlayerStateManager.instance.camState = 0;
            lockOnMoveR = false;
            lockOnMoveL = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found the issue.

For this solution to work, I'll assume due to the way your scene and project is set up, you only need to check the X position of enemies relative to each other (Shooting range, 2D games, etc), I reached this conclusion due to these lines:

```cs
var distanceFromLeftTarget = currentTarget.transform.position.x - availableTargets[i].transform.position.x;
var distanceFromRightTarget = currentTarget.transform.position.x + availableTargets[i].transform.position.x;
```

Which are actually where your problem might be.

I think the problem has to do with the way you are calculating distance, if you go to an XY plane and try doing the math you are doing by hand, you'll realize that you are not actually doing what you think you are doing. The basic formula for distance is something like `distance = |other - from|`

So, taking that into account, I would try changing your logic to be something like this

```cs
Vector3 relativeEnemyPos = currentTarget.transform.InverseTransformPoint(availableTargets[i].transform.position);
if (relativeEnemyPos.x  <= 0.00) continue;

var distanceToNewTarget = availableTargets[i].transform.position.x - currentTarget.transform.position.x;

if (distanceToNewTarget < 0 && Mathf.Abs(distanceToNewTarget) < shortestDistanceLeft)
{
    shortestDistanceLeft = Mathf.Abs(distanceToNewTarget);
    leftLockTarget = availableTargets[i];
}
else if (distanceToNewTarget > 0 && distanceToNewTarget < shortestDistanceRight)
{
    shortestDistanceRight = distanceToNewTarget;
    rightLockTarget = availableTargets[i];
}
```

This works by getting the relative X position of the new target you are testing to the current target, then depending on if the value is negative or positive, it decides if it's to the left or to the right, and then it sets the value if it's shorter than the shortest distance in that direction.

Hope I was able to help, let me know if it works!

Comment: Also, a little unrelated to the main problem, but I also noticed the `if(distanceToTarget >= maxLockDistance)` check in your `for` loop, which resets some things every time it finds a target out of the max lock on distance (and it's on a loop!), I don't know if that's really what you want to do...seems odd

Comment: Hey, this code is incredibly well written. However its having the same problem as the original of not updating the Right Lock Target. Thanks for trying though!